# What is the best way to store/ analyze data of a file (containing struct with bit fields)?

Tags: c, file, bit-fields

Having a file which contains blocks of data and each is of the following type:

```
struct block 
{ 
   int id : 4;
   int info : 5;
};
```

I need to print: for each `id` the sum of all its `info`s'. For example file contains at first data with `id` 2 and `info` 1 then `id` 3 and `info` 12, and finally `id` 2 and `info` 15, so the output should be like:

```
id: 2
info sum: 16

id: 3
info sum: 12
```

What is the best way to do so? Is managing array of structs is a good idea, or is there a better way?

The way I manage the struct is:

```
struct analyze_block 
{ 
   int id : 4;
   int sum_info : 12;
};
```

In a function which reads the data I'm putting `struct analyze_block record[15];` such that each record place in an array is consistent with its `id` so `record[2]` would have `id` 2. (BTW the array would be initialized at first to: `id` set to current record placing in array and `sum_info` to 0. So I would print only those with `sum_info` bigger then 0.)

Is there a better way to work/ analyze files with bit fields (or for this specific task)?

Comment: There are only 16 possible ID values — you can manage an array of that size easily.  However, the structures in the array will have a different type from the `struct block` that's stored on disk.  In fact, you don't even need a structure in the array; you can simply have an array of 16 `size_t` values (or `long long` if you expect the bit-field to be signed and holding negative values).

Comment: Unless, of course, you want the sum of the information modulo 2048 (or 4096 if your compiler treats `int` bit-fields as unsigned).  In that case, your don't need `struct analyze_block` as it is the same as `struct block`.

Comment: What if the number of possible ID values would be a much bigger, say `unsigned int id : 16;` ? @JonathanLeffler Thanks!!

Comment: 16 bits can hold (unsigned) values up to 64 K (65,536).  Most machines have multiple megabytes if not gigabytes of memory; 64 K of 8-byte counters is about half a megabyte.  Unless you're in a very constrained embedded system, 512 KiB isn't going to stress your system.